# why run k3s server on win11 wsl2 error:"Failed to start ContainerManager" err="system validation failed - wrong number of fields (expected 6, got 7)"

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

Before this error happens, I can rightly use the k3s server on wsl2.
But I have tried to install VMware and start a virtual Ubuntu on VMware.
I have uninstalled the whole files of VMware
But when running the k3s server, the error happens.

```
"unable to find data in memory cache" mountpoint="/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"
E0711 10:59:36.648074    2373 kubelet.go:1400] "Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet" err="invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem"
I0711 10:59:36.648588    2373 fs_resource_analyzer.go:67] "Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer"
I0711 10:59:36.648648    2373 volume_manager.go:284] "Starting Kubelet Volume Manager"
I0711 10:59:36.648725    2373 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:145] "Desired state populator starts to run"
I0711 10:59:36.649583    2373 server.go:461] "Adding debug handlers to kubelet server"
I0711 10:59:36.666612    2373 cpu_manager.go:214] "Starting CPU manager" policy="none"
I0711 10:59:36.666632    2373 cpu_manager.go:215] "Reconciling" reconcilePeriod="10s"
I0711 10:59:36.666640    2373 state_mem.go:36] "Initialized new in-memory state store"
I0711 10:59:36.666717    2373 state_mem.go:88] "Updated default CPUSet" cpuSet=""
I0711 10:59:36.666733    2373 state_mem.go:96] "Updated CPUSet assignments" assignments=map[]
I0711 10:59:36.666749    2373 policy_none.go:49] "None policy: Start"
I0711 10:59:36.667119    2373 memory_manager.go:169] "Starting memorymanager" policy="None"
I0711 10:59:36.667134    2373 state_mem.go:35] "Initializing new in-memory state store"
I0711 10:59:36.667203    2373 state_mem.go:75] "Updated machine memory state"
E0711 10:59:36.667341    2373 kubelet.go:1480] "Failed to start ContainerManager" err="system validation failed - wrong number of fields (expected 6, got 7)"
```

I use wsl2-ubuntu on win11. And docker-desktop on win11.
I have installed the latest version k3s from GitHub.

I want to know how to solve this problem and run k3s server

Comment: Even I reinstall my win11 and wsl2-ubuntu, this error still exited.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup as you, and I ran into the same problem.

Initially, things were running smoothly. But the next day, I woke my laptop up from hibernation, and the issue you described above started occurring.

A couple of notes:

- You must configure WSL2 to work with [`systemd`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/#set-the-systemd-flag-set-in-your-wsl-distro-settings).
- You don't need a docker engine, as k3s comes build-in with containerd (a container runtime) and is set by default to use it instead of docker:

> K3s includes and defaults to containerd ([source](https://docs.k3s.io/advanced#using-docker-as-the-container-runtime))

After a Windows restart, k3s went back to functioning normally.

(note that I restarted wsl after configuring it to work with `systemd`, but perhaps it wasn't enough).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Actually, I solved this problem by changing the docker of wsl2. I tried to install and use native docker in my wsl2-ubuntu instead of using docker-desktop. Surprisingly, this way is useful and my k3s server runs successfully.